# Polymer 1.0+ notify true not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am not sure what is going on in my code here and could use some pointers as to what might be happening.

A little background...

I want to have "pizza" pass its changes to "selectedItem" when anything in "pizza" changes.

Now for the code:

The following is my child element js:

```
Polymer({
  is:"order-pizza-mod",
  behaviors: [
    Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior
  ],
  properties: {
    mobile: {
      observer: "screenSizeChanged"
    },
    pizza: {
      notify: true,
      observer: "selectedPizza"
    },
....
  addToOrder: function () {  //this is the function that will need to update my parent element.
    this.set("pizza.ADD",true);
    this.fire('selectPage',4);
    console.log("SENT CHANGES");
    console.log(this.pizza);
  },
....
```

The following is my parent elements HTML and JS:

HTML:

```
<neon-animated-pages id="pages" selected="[[selected]]" class="overflow-catch">
        ...
    <!-- 7 --><order-pizza-mod pizza="{{selectedItem}}"></order-pizza-mod>
        ...
</neon-animated-pages>
```

JS:

```
Polymer({
  is:"page-order",
  behaviors: [
    Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior
  ],
  properties: {
...
    selectedItem: {
      observer:"selectionChanged"
    },
  },
....
  selectionChanged: function () {
    console.log("YAY, got all the things!");
  },
....
```

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What is the current behavior?

Comment: I expect a console log to happen that says "Yay, got all the things!" when i change something in "pizza' of the child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
properties: {
  selectedItem: {
    observer:"selectionChanged"
  }
}
```

do this

```
observers: [
  'selectionChanged(selectedItem.*)'
]
```

The problem is that `selectedItem` is only considered changed if references an entirely new object. But you are trying to observe changes to *properties* of `selectedItem`, which requires you to observe `selectedItem.*`.

Comment: Interesting. That's a good point I didn't think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution but it isn't very nice.

The problem resides here:

```
this.set("pizza.ADD",true);
```

Currently there is an open issue with polymer that "this.set" function does not trigger notify. I also tried "notifyPath" as well and that doesn't work. The only thing that I found to force polymer to trigger notify is to reassign the variable to a new object like this:

```
addToOrder: function () {  //this is the function that will need to update my parent element.
    this.pizza = {'ADD': true,
                  'CODE':this.pizza.CODE,
                  'GARNISHES':this.pizza.GARNISHES};

    this.fire('selectPage',4);
    console.log("SENT CHANGES");
    console.log(this.pizza);
},
```

This is messy but works with forcing polymer to notify a data bound variable. Now if anyone knows a better way of doing this please let me know.